# SQL join best matcher

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table A:

I need to join (SQL) this table onto table B, where I use ProductName as a join, but I want the following order of priorities:

1. Country being selected as a single row if it has a value (With Standard being null)
2. Using  the combination of Country and Standard
3. Using Standard by itself (If Country being null).

I have tried looking around a lot. I hope the problem statement is clear.

Table A:

```
|ProductName|Country|Standard|Reportable|
|ProductA|Null|Value1|Y|
|ProductA|Value2|Value1|N|
|ProductA|Value2|Null|N|
```

The above is just a subset of the data, but basically the country and standard determine if the output is reportable. Product A could have 1 line or 3, depending on the data required.

Table B:

```
|ProductName|Year|
|ProductA|2006|
```

So the final join for the above should be:

```
|ProductName|Year|Country|Standard|Reportable|
|ProductA|2006|Value2|Null|N|
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output

Comment: Can you add table structure, and maybe a little set o data?

Comment: I tried but seems to be missing, let me try again

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this: this is pseudo code at this time but hopefully gets the general concepts across.

Does assume A, B tables product are inner join related and not outer join.

- the 1st CTE sets your priority. CTE (Common Table Expression)
- the 2nd cte assigns a row number based on your priorities.
- then the final query filters for the first row number encountered.

Obviously this is untested as we have no sample data or structure to test with at this time.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT A.*
     , B.*
     , CASE WHEN A.Attribute is not null and B.attribute is null then 1
            WHEN A.Attribute is not null and B.attribute is not null then 2
            WHEN A.Attribute is null and B.Attribute is not null then 3 end as priority
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B
  on A.PRODUCT = B.PRODUCT),

CTE2 as (
SELECT CTE.*
     , rowNumber() over (Order by Priority desc) RN
FROM CTE)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE2 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
SELECT s.*, p.*
FROM   source_table s
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT p.*
              FROM   product_table p
              WHERE  p.product_name = s.product_name
              AND    ( ( p.country = s.country AND s.standard IS NULL )
                    OR ( p.country = s.country AND p.standard = s.standard )
                    OR ( s.country IS NULL AND p.standard = s.standard )
              ORDER BY CASE 
                   WHEN ( p.country = s.country AND s.standard IS NULL ) THEN 1
           WHEN ( p.country = s.country AND p.standard = s.standard ) THEN 2
           WHEN ( s.country IS NULL AND p.standard = s.standard ) THEN 3
                   ELSE 99
              FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY )
```

`OUTER APPLY` (instead of `CROSS APPLY`) keeps your `source_table` result even if there is no product match.  That may not be your desired outcome.  If not, switch to `CROSS APPLY`.

There are probably ways to shorten the conditions and the sort order using `NVL()`.  But I think this is the clearest way to start.

Also, if this is always a product match using one of those three conditions, you can shorten the `WHERE` clause in the `OUTER APPLY`.